# Bootstrap 3.3 button css text break in mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a problem with a button where the text breaks on a smaller resolution. I want to make it responsive so it stays the same at any resolution and I'm using Bootstrap 3.3

```
<button ng-show="vm.account.state === 'paused'" class="bm-badge bm-badge-danger "  ng-click="vm.corrigir()">
            <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Iniciar
        </button>
```

How it is supposed to look (screen shot with higher resolution):
[image: How it is supposed to look (screen shot with higher resolution)]

With 370px it breaks and looks like this:
[image: With 370px it breaks and looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea for you: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/xBZwbr

The important bit is that you want to have your button text to respond to the viewport, and one way to do this is using the vw unit (viewport width)
eg `font-size:calc(10px + 1vw);`

- increasing or decreasing 10px will control the font size on the smallest screens
- increasing or decreasing 1vw will control how the font size responds to the viewport width

Hope this helps!

---

**HTML**

```
<button  class="btn btn-danger ">
 <i class="fa fa-play"></i> Iniciar
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn{
  font-size:calc(10px + 1vw); /* the important bit */
  padding:10px 20px;
  border-radius:calc(10px + 2vw);
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 )
}


/* Optional: if space is tight, hide play icon at small viewport */

.fa.fa-play{
  display:none;
}

@media (min-width: 350px) {
  .fa.fa-play{
    display:inline;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Unfortunately it didn't work i tried using in the button 

display: flex;

But it is now the icon and the button stuck together with the text and the button top part. :/

Comment: Can you share the page URL? There aren't enough details in the code you posted to reproduce what you are seeing.